# DatagramSocket only receives one packet when used on network

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I have a server and a client. If I run both on my own computer the connection between them works fine. I can log in to the client, it sends information to the server and when I close it down the session is saved in the server.

If I run the server on my computer, and the client on any other computer, only one packet is received by the server. This means I can log in, but no other packets are received by either system and the session is not saved when I close.

It worked flawlessly a few weeks ago and I can't figure out what is wrong.

EDIT: I haven't included any code because it's a massive project at this point and I was just hoping the problem would sound familiar to someone.

Comment: You say it's a massive project, but you can probably produce a minimal version that illustrates the error. In my experience, the exercise of producing   a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) often leads to discovery of the problem on your own. If not, you can post your mcve in your question and you'll  be much more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: *...If I run the server on my computer, and the client on any other computer, only one packet is received by the server. ...* - What happens to other packets? Does it throw any exception/error? Also, can you share the code as to how are you sending and receiving the packets. **NOTE: Those are Datagram packets (delivery is not guaranteed)**